# "NoneType" Task cannot be store a value

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm just trying to implementation stop command with Task but program returns this code
 `[AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cancel']`
that seems global value didn't store, am I missing knowledge about global value?
how should I implementation this command

```
import discord
import asyncio

task = None


async def start(message):
    while True:
        await message.channel.send("loop")
        await asyncio.sleep(10)

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))

    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author == client.user:
            return

        if message.content.startswith("!p start"):
            global task
            task = await client.loop.create_task(start(message))

        elif message.content.startswith("!p stop"):
            task.cancel()
            task = None


client = MyClient()
client.run('TOKEN')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pass
```

**Reformat dumb codes**

```
import discord
import asyncio


class TaskStore():
    global task

    def __init__(self, task):
        self.task = task


async def start(message):
    while True:
        await message.channel.send("loop")
        await asyncio.sleep(10)


class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))

    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author == client.user:
            return

        if message.content.startswith("!p start"):
            TaskStore.task = await client.loop.create_task(start(message))

        elif message.content.startswith("!p stop"):
            TaskStore.task.cancel()
            TaskStore.task = None
        else:
            print("not working")


client = MyClient()
client.run('TOKEN')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pass
```

**Error**

> Ignoring exception in on_message Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "discord\client.py", line 270, in _run_event
>       await coro(*args, **kwargs)   File "main.py", line 30, in on_message
>       TaskStore.task.cancel() AttributeError: type object 'TaskStore' has no attribute 'task'

Comment: at start you set `task = None` and later you may have message with `"!p stop"` so it will execute `None.cancel()`. You have to check `if task is not None` before you can use `task.cancel()`

Comment: if you use create class then you could use `self.task` instead of `global`.

Comment: oops, I'm sorry forgot to paste all error code
also, I fixed my dumb code

Comment: I was thinking about `self.task` created inside `MyClient`, not in new class. :) But if you use `TaskStore` and `__init__` then I would expect you will create instance of `TaskStore` like `t = TaskStore(some_task)`.

Comment: as I said before code `TaskStore.task.cancel()` can be executed before `TaskStore.task = await client.loop.create_task(start(message))` so you may get `None.cancel()`.  You have to check `if TaskStore.task is not None: TaskStore.cancel()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was completely confused, there is the code that I was trying to implement
I appreciate furas, Thank you for helping me with it!

**SOLVED**

```
import discord
import asyncio


class TaskStore():
    task = None

    def __init__(self, task):
        self.task = task


async def start(message):
    while True:
        await message.channel.send("loop")
        await asyncio.sleep(10)


class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))

    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author == client.user:
            return

        if message.content.startswith("!p start"):
            if TaskStore.task != True:
                global task
                task = client.loop.create_task(start(message))
                TaskStore.task = True
            else:
                await message.channel.send("bot is currently working on it")
        elif message.content.startswith("!p stop"):
            if TaskStore.task is not None and not False:
                task.cancel()
                TaskStore.task = False
                await message.channel.send("bot will be off")
            else:
                await message.channel.send("bot is currently not working")


client = MyClient()
client.run('TOKEN')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pass
```